# How can I parse .unity3d file on sever side by php

Tags: php, unity-game-engine

I have my own .unity3d files on my server for downloading by users to update our game. And I try to create a web-interface to add some additional data linked to this .unity3d files. This interface have to be able to show images from assets from .unity3d files. These files conain .png asset and information about sprites. How can i parse .unity3d file to show images from it in my web-interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unity3d files are a proprietary package format used for distribution, and thus are not meant to be edited.

If you need to build your web interface it will be easier to do so using the original files.

Having said that, there are tools that decompile .unity3d files [See this answer in the Unity official SO](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/135253/how-do-i-open-unity3d-files.html)